# smooth scroll to div on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked through a lot of smooth scrolling stuff and none of them do quite exactly what I want it to do. I would like to encapsulate a mouse scroll, and automatically smooth scroll to a specific div. So there the user is never *between* two divs, the screen is always filled with the next or previous div. Kind of like a hyperlink that jumps to an #anchor but instead of a click, its a mouse scroll, and instead of a jump, its a smooth scroll/transition. Simplest solution would be best. I don't want to involve jquery...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good plugin for doing what you want.

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: The link is dead